# Vertical ScrollView not scrolling (No Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I need help creating a Scroll View without Storyboards. Here is my code for setting up the Scroll View; I'm not setting a contentSize of the Scroll View because I'd like the scroll view content size to be dynamic, dependent on the amount of text in the TextView. What I did instead, is I tried adding a 'contentView' to the Scroll View and added all my UI elements into the contentView. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import UITextView_Placeholder

class ComposerVC: UIViewController {
  
  private var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
  }()
  
  private var contentView: UIView = {
    let content = UIView()
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return content
  }()
  
  private var title: UITextView = {
    let title = UITextView()
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    title.placeholder = "Untitled"
    title.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#50E3C2")
    title.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-BoldItalic", size: 32)
    title.backgroundColor = .clear
    title.isScrollEnabled = false
    return title
  }()
  
  private var divider: UIView = {
    let divider = UIView()
    divider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    divider.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#50E3C2")
    return divider
  }()
  
  private var content: UITextView = {
    let title = UITextView()
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    title.placeholder = "Begin writing here..."
    title.textColor = .white
    title.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 15)
    title.backgroundColor = .clear
    title.isScrollEnabled = false
    return title
  }()
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    setupUI()
    setupUIConstraints()
    title.delegate = self
  }
  
  private func setupUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#131415")
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.addSubview(title)
    contentView.addSubview(divider)
    contentView.addSubview(content)
  }
  
  private func setupUIConstraints() {
    
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 95).isActive = true
    title.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    title.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
    
    divider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: title.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    divider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    divider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
    divider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
    
    content.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    content.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
    content.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
  }
}

extension ComposerVC: UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple tips:

1. Don't use existing names for variables... with your code as-is, `private var title: UITextView` causes problems (`title` is already a view controller property).
2. Use var names that imply the object... e.g. `titleTextView` and `contentTextView` instead of `title` and `content`
3. During development - particularly when you're working on layout - give your UI elements contrasting background colors so you can easily see their frames at runtime.
4. When using code-created views, set `.clipsToBounds = true` ... if you don't see any subviews you've added, you know the frame / constraints are missing something.

I don't have your `UITextView_Placeholder` import, but that shouldn't affect anything here...

So, first, change your `viewDidLoad()` to this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setupUI()
    setupUIConstraints()
    titleTextView.delegate = self
    
    // contrasting colors during development
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
    titleTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    contentTextView.backgroundColor = .green
    divider.backgroundColor = .blue
    contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
}
```

When you run it, you should see (scroll view background is red, and this is without the placeholder stuff):

[image]

It *looks* correct, except there's no cyan-colored `contentView`.

Now, clip the subviews of `contentView`:

```
private var contentView: UIView = {
    let content = UIView()
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // add this line
    content.clipsToBounds = true
    return content
}()
```

The result:

[image]

Where did everything go? Well, we ***didn't*** see the cyan `contentView` and now we don't see any of its ***subviews*** ... If we use `Debug View Hierarchy` we can find out `contentView` has a Height of Zero.

Fix that by constraining the bottom of the second text view in `setupUIConstraints()` (I've renamed it to `contentTextView` instead of just `content`):

```
    contentTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -95).isActive = true
```

and we get:

[image]

Now the Height of the cyan `contentView` is controlled by correctly setup constraints of its subviews.

As a side note: with constraints setup properly, and scrolling disabled for the text views, you do not need your:

```
extension ComposerVC: UITextViewDelegate {
  //func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
  //...
  //}
}
```

The text view will automatically size itself to its text:

[image]

Here's the complete edited code:

```
class ComposerVC: UIViewController {
    
    private var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    private var contentView: UIView = {
        let content = UIView()
        content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // add this line so we know if the constraints are set correctly
        content.clipsToBounds = true
        return content
    }()
    
    private var titleTextView: UITextView = {
        let title = UITextView()
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//      title.placeholder = "Untitled"
        title.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#50E3C2")
        title.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-BoldItalic", size: 32)
        title.backgroundColor = .clear
        title.isScrollEnabled = false
        return title
    }()
    
    private var divider: UIView = {
        let divider = UIView()
        divider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        divider.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#50E3C2")
        return divider
    }()
    
    private var contentTextView: UITextView = {
        let title = UITextView()
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//      title.placeholder = "Begin writing here..."
        title.textColor = .white
        title.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 15)
        title.backgroundColor = .clear
        title.isScrollEnabled = false
        return title
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupUI()
        setupUIConstraints()
        titleTextView.delegate = self
        
        // contrasting colors during development
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        titleTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        contentTextView.backgroundColor = .green
        divider.backgroundColor = .blue
        contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#131415")
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(titleTextView)
        contentView.addSubview(divider)
        contentView.addSubview(contentTextView)
    }
    
    private func setupUIConstraints() {
        
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        
        titleTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 95).isActive = true
        titleTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
        titleTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
        
        divider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        divider.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        divider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
        divider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
        
        contentTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: divider.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
        contentTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 35).isActive = true
        contentTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -35).isActive = true
        
        contentTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -95).isActive = true
    
    }
}

extension ComposerVC: UITextViewDelegate {
//  func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
//      let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
//      let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
//      textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
//  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using iOS 11+, Your contentView should have its anchors constrained to the contentLayoutGuide of the scrollView. like this:

```swift
contentView
    .leadingAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView
    .topAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
contentView
    .trailingAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView
    .bottomAnchor
    .constraint(equalTo: scrollView.contentLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Also, its width should be constrained to the scrollView's frameLayoutGuide and not the view's width, like this:

```swift
contentView
.widthAnchor
.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

That should make the scrollView detect the content size to fit.